# How to resolve chromedriver_binary and Chrome versions not matching?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning to perform webscraping for finance.

I am following a tutorial. I am required to import selenium and chromedriver_binary. I am using Windows 10, conda, and Spyder 5.

I have downloaded the latest version of Chrome I can, which is version 92.0.4515.159. I have also installed into my conda environment chromedriver-binary which is version 93.

I understand that both chrome and chromedriver need to match at the version level, 92-92 for example. However, I am not able to download Chrome 93 yet, unless the beta version is okay. I am unsure.

I have visited the chromium downloads page where I downloaded chromedriver for version 92. I have also created a PATH variable to my C: drive as C:\bin where I store my chromedriver.exe. I verified that this has worked by opening a cmd prompt and running chromedriver.exe -v

Of course, then, my error message in Spyder is:
SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93 Current browser version is 92.0.4515.159 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Can someone please help me resolve this issue? Thank you! =)

Comment: Did you try passing this argument `driver = webdriver.Chrome("path_to_92_version_chromedriver")` ?

Comment: No I did not. But I just did and it failed with this error message: WebDriverException: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

HOWEVER! Upon googling your suggestion, I found that by running:
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/path/to/driver') **the little r there** DID fix the problem. Might you know why? THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR SUGGESTION ^___^

Comment: Raw String `r''` ignores the string literals. You were probably using a backslash in your `executable_path` so using raw string worked for you. Exactly same thing which I tried to convey.
So It looks my suggestion helped you? Will you accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using the PATH variables by simply passing the `executable_path` while calling the Chrome.

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver")
```

Refer to [Webdrive Documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=executable_path%20#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.__init__) for detailed read.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `chromedriver` version cannot be higher then the browser version so the only way to solve this problem is to [download](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and install the `chromedriver` version compatible (and in this case **equal**) to your browser version. Then, as already suggested, use the `executable_path` when creating your driver like this: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/path/to/chromedriver")` as argument. To be sure which `chromedriver`  version you are using you can check it like this: `/path/to/chromedriver --version`